# How can I store my api's data link to my MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How can I store `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects` to my MongoDB using Node.js? I call a request function which I get a JSON object and I parse it correctly. I also make sure I am connected to my MongoDB which I am. Now how do I transfer that data to my db?

I've tried mongoose, but I am probably not doing it correctly. I have also tried the function `.insertMany(json, ...)`

```
//git.server.js
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    url: 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects',
    method: 'GET'
};

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
    //export to mongodb
});


//app.js
const request = require('request');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@gitlab-tools-hs5yh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("DBname").collection("User");
    console.log('here');

    client.close();
});
```